# Retrieving Attribute from json? PHP

Tags: php, json

I have this partial json:

```
string(1583) "[{"user_id":"U4qtgydvSgG9zV9F"}]
```

How do i get the user_id value?

I tried this:

```
$json = json_decode($res);
$UserId = $res->user_id;
```

But i dont hit the user_id.

Then i tried to cast the result to an array an access the user_id like this:

```
$res = (array)file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
echo $res['user_id'];
```

The array looks like this:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(1583) "[{"user_id":"U4qtgydvSgG9zV9F-NB2rQ"
```

How do i get the user_id value? Thanks

Comment: Try this: `$UserId = $res[0]->user_id;`

Comment: The JSON string you post is not valid, and without the rest it's not possible to see the structure.

Comment: You need to strip off the 'string(1583)' part for a start as that is not part of the json. Where is the json string coming from, it looks like the result of a var_dump() to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see this json example:

```
$j = '[{"user_id":"U4qtgydvSgG9zV9F"}]';
$j = json_decode($j);
echo $j[0]->user_id;
```